# I want that user will automatically redirected to next li when clicks on next button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#mynextlink').on('click', function() {

    debugger;
    //var linkss = $('.selectedul li').next('.selectedul li').find('a').attr('href');
    var linkss = $('.selectedul li').parent().prev().find('a');
    $('#mynextlink').attr("href", linkss);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" id="social">
  <ul id="gallery" class="list-group selectedul">
    <li data-index="0" id="listitem" class="list-group-item  "><a list-link="1" id="myreflink" href="/User/BusinessPlanSummary" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 1: Business Plan Summary</a></li>
    <li data-index="1" id="listitem" class="list-group-item disabledClass "><a list-link="2" id="myreflink" href="/User/BindGrids?type=1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 2: P&amp;L Details</a></li>
    <li data-index="2" id="listitem" class="list-group-item disabledClass "><a list-link="3" id="myreflink" href="/User/BindGrids?type=2" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 3: Balance Sheet Details</a></li>
    <li data-index="3" id="listitem" class="list-group-item disabledClass "><a list-link="4" id="myreflink" href="/User/ApprovalPlans?type=1&amp;approve=2" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 4: Final Step</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a id="mynextlink" class="nextspan">Next</a>
```

Above is my code. My requirement is that user will automatically gets shifted to the next li element when clicks on Next button. I have tried the code in jquery which is below but not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class `activeli` in the first li and change it with each click .Try following code. Hope it will work.

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body" id="social">
        <ul id="gallery" class="list-group selectedul">
        <li data-index="0" id="listitem" class="list-group-item  activeli"><a list-link="1" id="myreflink" href="/User/BusinessPlanSummary" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 1: Business Plan Summary</a></li><li data-index="1" id="listitem" class="list-group-item disabledClass "><a list-link="2" id="myreflink" href="/User/BindGrids?type=1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 2: P&amp;L Details</a></li><li data-index="2" id="listitem" class="list-group-item disabledClass "><a list-link="3" id="myreflink" href="/User/BindGrids?type=2" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 3: Balance Sheet Details</a></li><li data-index="3" id="listitem" class="list-group-item disabledClass "><a list-link="4" id="myreflink" href="/User/ApprovalPlans?type=1&amp;approve=2" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 4: Final Step</a></li></ul>
    </div>
<a id="mynextlink" class="nextspan">Next</a>
```

jquery

```
$('#mynextlink').on('click', function () {
    var $next;
    var $selected = $(".activeli");
    $next = $selected.next('li');

    $next = $selected.next('li');
    $selected.removeClass("disabledClass activeli");
    $('.selectedul li').addClass('disabledClass');
    $next.addClass('activeli');
    $next.removeClass('disabledClass');
    window.location.href = $('.activeli').find("a").attr('href');
});
```

Comment: This is just adding activeli class to next li element not able to redirect to next li @m354

Comment: I am not sure what will be the purpose of selecting next li. Because we can add css or  jquery if we want with activeli class. I updated my answer that will readjust disabledClass

Comment: My requirement is that when a user will click on next button it will automatically get navigated to the next li page @m354